# Linear Regression using fminunc Implementation

Tags: octave, linear-regression

I'm trying to implement linear regression with only one feature using `fminunc` in Octave.

Here is my code.

```matlab
x = load('/home/battousai/Downloads/ex2Data/ex2x.dat');
y = load('/home/battousai/Downloads/ex2Data/ex2y.dat');

m = length(y);
x = [ones(m , 1) , x];
theta = [0 , 0]';

X0 = [x , y , theta];

options = optimset('GradObj' , 'on' , 'MaxIter' , 1500);
[x , val] = fminunc(@computeCost , X0 , options)
```

And here is the cost function which returns the gradient as well as the value of the cost function.

```matlab
function [J , gradient] = computeCost(x , y , theta)
  m = length(y);
  J = (0.5 / m) .* (x * theta - y )' * (x * theta - y );
  gradient = (1/m) .* x' * (x * theta - y);
end
```

The length of the data set is `50`, i.e., the dimensions are `50 x 1`. I'm not getting the part that how should I pass `X0` to the `fminunc`.

Updated Driver Code:

```matlab
x = load('/home/battousai/Downloads/ex2Data/ex2x.dat');
y = load('/home/battousai/Downloads/ex2Data/ex2y.dat');

m = length(y);
x = [ones(m , 1) x];
theta_initial = [0 , 0];
options = optimset('Display','iter','GradObj','on' , 'MaxIter' , 100);
[X , Cost] = fminunc(@(t)(computeCost(x , y , theta)), theta_initial , options)
```

Updated Code for Cost function:

```matlab
function [J , gradient] = computeCost(x , y , theta)
  m = length(y);
  J = (1/(2*m)) * ((x * theta) - y )' * ((x * theta) - y) ;
  gradient = (1 / m) .* x' * ((x * theta) - y);  
end
```

Now I'm getting values of `theta` to be `[0,0]` but when I used normal equation, values of `theta` turned out to be `[0.750163 , 0.063881]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for fminunc:

> FCN should accept a vector (array) defining the unknown variables

and

> X0 determines a starting guess.

Since your input is a *cost* function (i.e. it associates your choice of parameter vector with a cost), the input argument to your cost function, that needs to be optimised via `fminunc` is only theta, since `x` and `y` (i.e. your observations and your targets) are considered 'given' aspects of the problem and are not things you're trying to optimise. So you either declare `x` and `y` global and access them from your function like so:

```
function [J , gradient] = computeCost(theta_0)
  global x; global y;
  % ...
```

and then call fminunc as: `fminunc (@computeCost, t_0, options)`

*or*, keep your computeCost function as `computeCost(x, y, theta)`, and change your `fminunc` call to something like this:

```
[x , val] = fminunc(@ (t) computeCost(x, y, t) , t0 , options)
```

---

**UPDATE** Not sure what you were doing wrong. Here is the full code and an octave session running it. Seems fine.

```
%% in file myscript.m
x = load('ex2x.dat');
y = load('ex2y.dat');

m = length(y);
x = [ones(m , 1) , x];
theta_0 = [0 , 0]';

options = optimset('GradObj' , 'on' , 'MaxIter' , 1500);
[theta_opt, cost] = fminunc(@ (t) computeCost(x,y,t) , theta_0 , options)
```

```
%% in file computeCost.m
function [J , gradient] = computeCost(x , y , theta)
  m = length(y);
  J = (0.5 / m) .* (x * theta - y )' * (x * theta - y );
  gradient = (1/m) .* x' * (x * theta - y);
end
```

```
%% in the octave terminal:
>> myscript
theta_opt =

   0.750163
   0.063881

cost =    9.8707e-04
```

Comment: Then How do I use given training data set ?

Comment: ah, apologies, I didn't study your problem beyond the obvious syntax error. `fminunc` is a minimization function for your 'dependent' variable. Therefore your cost function is purely a function of theta (and x and y are 'given'). Furthermore, X0 is not 'input' as such, but simply a starting guess. I'll edit to show this accordingly. Mind you without access to your data (or preferably a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) I can't do much more than general advice / educated guesses like this.

Comment: I used the second option and It's working now. But values that I'm getting for theta is [0 , 0] and cost is also 0 but when I used gradient descent, value of theta turns out to be [0.750163 , 0.063881]. I don't understand that !!

Comment: alas, I can't check this for myself without the dataset.

Comment: 1) https://pastebin.com/uU3phyJ2    -- feature dataset
2) https://pastebin.com/wMaMNPbW   -- and corresponding results

Comment: Thank you very much @tasos. I was passing the wrong argument in the cost function.
`fminunc(@(t)computeCost(x,y,theta) ,initital_theta , options)`
 **theta was the problem here**
I changed my code to `fminunc(@(theta)computeCost(x ,y , theta) , initial_theta , options)` And now it's working fine.
Again thank you so much @Tasos